# Get items where the difference between sets is non-empty

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Given that I have an array `["a", "b", "c"]`, I would like to fetch all documents where *any* of the elements is *not* present in a field. For instance, if I have the item:

```
{
    a: ["a", "b"]
}
```

Since "c" is not present it should be retrieved but not:

```
{
    a: ["a", "b", "c"]
}
```

How would I make this query with MongoDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$all` to match all the elements in `a`, and `$not` for negative condition for `$all` operation,

```
collection.find({
  a: {
    $not: {
      $all: ["a", "b", "c"]
    }
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/afRz10D9K5A)